# bitcount implementation in opencl

Tags: opencl, bit

I am interested in opencl implementation of kernel which counts set(1) bits in unsigned int
I know that there is such extension for opencl and I don`t want to use it ,but implement by myself

Answer (score 2):

This is not the exact function you are looking for. But since no one has posted OpenCL code, I will add it. It is OpenCL bit count code for 256 bit integers rather than for 32 bit as you requested. The code is from [here](http://notabs.org/blcutil). It uses one of the well known algorithms pointed out by Dithermaster. It should not be difficult to convert to 32-bit.

```
//
// popcnt256 - return population count for 256-bit value
//
uint popcnt256 (ulong4 vreg)
    {
    const ulong4 m1  = (ulong4)(0x5555555555555555,0x5555555555555555,0x5555555555555555,0x5555555555555555);
    const ulong4 m2  = (ulong4)(0x3333333333333333,0x3333333333333333,0x3333333333333333,0x3333333333333333);
    const ulong4 m4  = (ulong4)(0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f,0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f,0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f,0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f);
    const ulong4 h01 = (ulong4)(0x0101010101010101,0x0101010101010101,0x0101010101010101,0x0101010101010101);

    vreg -= (vreg >> 1) & m1;
    vreg = (vreg & m2) + ((vreg >> 2) & m2);
    vreg = (vreg + (vreg >> 4)) & m4;
    vreg = (vreg * h01) >> 56;
    return vreg.s0 + vreg.s1 + vreg.s2 + vreg.s3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the old-school CPU-based tricks apply here as well, although any that loop will not be great on the GPU. Probably a (non-global memory) table is going to work best.

See:

[How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-set-bits-in-an-integer/

http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/fast-bit-counting-routines/